# How to set and get Java bean static variable within javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsf

In my jsf page I am using navigation option usign HTML, CSS and Javascript.
It is working fine but problem is that I want to use and set java static variable value on my openNev() method. My java static variable 'nevOpenState' which is my class SelectedVehicleBean variable:

Here is my javascript functions for open and close navigation :

function openNav() {

```
            if(#{selectedVehicleBean.nevOpenState == true})
                document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";

                if (#{selectedVehicleBean.viewId eq '/jsf/mainTracking.xhtml'}) {
                    document.getElementById("gmapPanel").style.marginLeft = "250px";
                    document.getElementById("test2").style.marginLeft = "250px";

                } else {
                    document.getElementById("movementTabview").style.marginLeft = "250px";
                    document.getElementById("searchForm").style.marginLeft = "250px";
                }
            }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";

            if (#{selectedVehicleBean.viewId eq '/jsf/mainTracking.xhtml'}) {
                document.getElementById("gmapPanel").style.marginLeft = "0";
                document.getElementById("test2").style.marginLeft = "0";

            } else {
                document.getElementById("movementTabview").style.marginLeft = "0";
                document.getElementById("searchForm").style.marginLeft = "0";
            }

        }
```

I am successfully getting  #{selectedVehicleBean.nevOpenState == true} but how can I set false value in selectedVehicleBean.nevOpenState when navigation close?

Comment: You should not use static variables in this way. I suggest a rethink

Comment: Any possibility or any other way?

Comment: I'm guessing you want something that is request or perhaps session scoped. You'll likely use the "M" in [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: But I not know the code implementation of it. Kindly give me the example code or any reference link for this?